# An educational game for learning programming?

Tags: java

Is there any fun, educational game (maybe a flash game, etc.) that help learning the concept of programming and training your brain to think like a programmer?

Actually, I am not the one who will be playing it; it'd be my friend instead.  I tried to help out my best friend through the university Java course (at my university, it is a kinda "sucky" course). I have practiced programming for many years, so for me it is not a problem. However, my best friend, whose major is not in computer engineering (but must take this course due to it being required), has a very hard time being introduce to Java by the boring professor and very confusing textbook.

I tried to simplify many context for my friend, but still it seems he gets bored with those confusing context very fast. Therefore, if possible, I'd like to introduce it to him in a more enjoying way such as a game.

Comment: I suggest www.codecademy.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several games available, this one is closest to programming and fun I've encountered so far:

[light-Bot](http://www.kongregate.com/games/Coolio_Niato/light-bot)

[light-Bot 2.0](http://www.kongregate.com/games/Coolio_Niato/lighbot-2-0)

**Update**
Here are the newest versions of the game, which include better explanatory texts and a friendlier drag/drop interface:

[Lightbot](http://light-bot.com)

And a version for young kids in particular: [ages 4-8]

[Lightbot JR](http://light-bot.com)

Answer (score 4):

http://codingbat.com/ 
It might not look like a game.

But it's a site, that offers easily understandable problems, ranging from complete beginner problems to intermediate problems. Split up into categories based on the subject they're covering.

You write the code on the site, and then it tests it, and shows you the results.
The game part comes in when you complete an assignment and it gives you a point! (In the form of a star).

The constant gratification of being rewarded when you solve a problem makes for a much more pleasing and interesting learning experience I've found... It helped me and my classmates a lot when we had an incompetent Java teacher :p

Answer (score 1):

[Manufactoria](http://www.pleasingfungus.com/)

Comment: This one reminds of manufactoria. The fact that you use boxes that you built is previous levels is a nice touch: http://jayisgames.com/games/jahoomas-logic-box/

Answer (score 1):

there was the game called [Colobot](http://www.ceebot.com/colobot/index-e.php) days ago

Comment: There **is** a game. It is still maintained as an open source project and it's available on [github](https://github.com/colobot/colobot).

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep updated, there is a new game CodeSpells which is quite an interesting game.

> In the gameplay, the player is a wizard arriving in a land populated by gnomes, which is a group who used to have magic powers but lost it. The wizard has to help gnomes by writing spells in Java. Players have seven spells available to use, including levitating objects within the game, flying and making fire.

See: [CodeSpells First-person Player Video Game Teaches Kids How To Program In Java](http://www.redorbit.com/news/technology/1112820733/java-programming-video-game-for-school-students-041113/)

Answer (score 0):

[CeeBot](http://www.ceebot.com/ceebot/index-e.php) is great.

Answer (score 0):

What about programming like playing a game:

[Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/) is a programming language that makes it easy to create your own interactive stories, animations, games, music, and art -- and share your creations on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing [`hangman`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_%28game%29), [`tic-tac-toe`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) ( 2 player version to start with and later can be modified to play with computer).